# Need a SQL query to get data based on condition based on count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have tables called `areadetail` and `state`.

`areadetail` has these columns:

```
State Id
Area Id-rural(1) or urban(2)
Population
```

Sample data:

```
Stateid                AreaID                    Population
1                        1                           10
1                        2                           20
1                        2                           20
2                        1                           10
2                        2                           20
3                        1                           10
```

`State` table has these columns:

```
State name and state id
```

Sample data:

```
State Id                    StateName
1                             Delhi
2                             Mumbai
3                             Jaipur
```

Now I need a query to display records like

```
State name      Rural               Urban
------------------------------------------
Delhi            3                   2
Mumbai           1                   1
Jaipur           1                   0
```

Comment: how you get for Delhi Rural 3 and urban 2 ???

Comment: they are the count of records we have in db

Comment: so why for Mumbai Urban you get 2 ?? because there is one record

Answer (score 1):

I guess `AreaID=1` means `RURAL` and `2` is `URBAN` then try this query:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(s.StateName),
  SUM(CASE WHEN ad.AreaID=1 THEN ad.Population ELSE 0 END) as Rural ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ad.AreaID=2 THEN ad.Population ELSE 0 END) as Urban


FROM State as s
LEFT JOIN areadetail as ad on s.Stateid=ad.Stateid
GROUP BY s.Stateid
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11aca/6)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for ur help but need the above result as tehre is lil bit changes

Comment: @user2640656 Then change `THEN ad.Population ELSE 0 END` to `THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` in both expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Select name,Rural,Urban

from
(

Select state, sum(case when area= 1 then 1 else 0 end) 'Rural',sum(case when area= 2 then 1
 else 0 end)  'Urban'

from #Area

group by state

) A
join State S
on A.state = S.state